# Why does git diff fail to work on changes in subdirectories?

Tags: git-diff, subdirectory

Why does git diff fail to work on changes in subdirectories?

When I do a `git diff *c` and the `C` files are in subdirectories, git outputs an error message.

```
 $ git diff *c                                                      
 fatal: ambiguous argument '*c': unknown revision or path not in the
 working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like
 this: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

What option is required to make git diff to list changes in the subdirectories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the command is missing quotes and they are not optional:

```
   $ git diff -- '*.c'
```